# Twig custom function with parameters

Tags: twig

I read twig documentation, but I am little confused about custom functions and filters. I understand how to add custom functions. But I don't understand how to write a function that accepts some parameters, may be also some optional parameters.

For example, I have following pseudo code for function named sqare.

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('square', function () {
    if param2 present?
     return param1*param2;
    else
     return param1;
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Now what I want is that, param1 should have a default value 1 and param2 should be optional. The square function will return the product of the two parameters. I also want that if user do not pass the second parameter then param1 will be returned, that is the first parameter will be returned. How can I implement this? Also, should I call the function in the twig template as `{{ square(5, 10) }}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the parameters in your `closure`.
Twig will pass the parameters accordingly

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('square', function ($param1, $param2 = null) {
    return isset($param2) ? $param1 * $param2 : $param1;
});
```

Then you call this function in `Twig` with :

```
Only one param : {{ square(5) }}
Two params : {{ square(5, 2) }}
```